# Please be careful when reviewing tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, reviewing

When reviewing tag wiki edits, please be careful to ensure that the proposed entry is appropriate to Computer Science SE. The tag wiki is supposed to explain how the tag relates to this site. Entries that only define what the tag means have little value, as people who want to know the definition of a term are much more likely to go to Wikipedia.

In particular, material in the tag wiki should not be copied wholesale from elsewhere. This is one of the grounds for rejection in the review dialogs:

> This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Material that is copied wholesale from another place is inappropriate for the tag wiki because it fails to explain how the tag relates to this specific site. Either it explains the term in general, or it explains how the tag relates to some other site.

Some warning signs that text might not be appropriate for this site because it has been copied from elsewhere:

- The [suggested edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27376) includes phrases such as "[Subject]-related tags:" followed by a whole bunch of tags that don't even exist here and contains a bunch of links to programming tutorials.
- The [suggested edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27374) includes phrases such as "NOTE: If you want to use this tag for a question not directly concerning implementation, then consider posting on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) instead. Otherwise you're probably off-topic."

**And, expletive, read the expletive suggested edit before expletive approving it, OK?** That will take more than four seconds. If you don't have more than four seconds, hit the "skip" button.

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue! Is there anything that requires moderator intervention? Feel free to flag liberally; I for one don't keep an eye on tag wikis much.

Comment: @Raphael I don't think there's anything that needs intervention: I rolled back the edits (manually, since there seems to be no rollback option on the tag wiki). Worth poking the reviewers?

Comment: If you know who they are and they are repeating offenders, poking them may be advisable. We can not be sure they read this. I guess this would be a proper use-case for that sudo-ping in chat.

Comment: Gilles has written an excellent [guide to tag wiki entries](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/2125/52332) for IT Security SE. Almost all of it applies directly here on CS, with an `s/security/computer science/g`.

Answer (score 1):

I was a generator for such wikis. My mistake was that I copied the wiki from Stackoverflow and pasted it in cs's wiki.

That's wrong, because:

**The tag wiki is supposed to explain how the tag relates to this site.**

Comment: Thanks for caring!

Comment: Of course @Raphael! Always a pleasure!